# Wrap javascript element in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

The following code copies all elements given one css class, that's fine, it does render the list of elements... Now I'd like to wrap those results in HTML content, how can I achieve that?

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("unique_ID");
  element.innerHTML = "";
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".a_random_class"), function(e) {
    var storednode = element.appendChild(e.cloneNode(true));

  });
}, 300);
```

How can I wrap in HTML content each of the *storednode*? I've been able to apply classes: `storednode.className += " another-class";`, but how can I wrap the results in any HTML I want? is that possible?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

This is what the script does.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.getElementById("unique_ID");
  element.innerHTML = "";
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".a_random_class"), function(e) {
    element.appendChild(e.cloneNode(true));
  });
}, 300);
```

```css
#unique_ID {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="unique_ID"></div>
<div class="a_random_class">a</div>
<div class="a_random_class">b</div>
<div class="a_random_class">c</div>
<div class="a_random_class">d</div>
<div class="a_random_class">e</div>
<div class="a_random_class">f</div>
```

What I need is that each result, for example `<div class="a_random_class">f</div>` can be wrapped inside any HTML code I want, to get something like `<div id="another-div" class="a-class" style="maybe:styles"><li><div class="a_random_class">f</div></li></div>` This is certainly an example, but I'd like to know if that's possible... Not only copy the class elements but also append some HTML on them.

Comment: sorry.. what are you really trying to do? can you give us a markup sample and the how the desired output should look like

Comment: @ArunPJohny done, please check the thread once again :) thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is something like

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.className = 'something';
    [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".a_random_class"), function (e) {
        var wrap = element.cloneNode(true);
        e.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, e)
        wrap.appendChild(e);
    });
}, 300);
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  var element = document.createElement('div');
  element.className = 'something';
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".a_random_class"), function(e) {
    var wrap = element.cloneNode(true);
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(wrap, e)
    wrap.appendChild(e);
  });
}, 300);
```

```css
.something {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.a_random_class {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="a_random_class">a</div>
<div class="a_random_class">b</div>
<div class="a_random_class">c</div>
<div class="a_random_class">d</div>
<div class="a_random_class">e</div>
<div class="a_random_class">f</div>
```

Comment: Hi @ArunPJohny thank you for time. Hmm let me workaround it and I'll let you know in a few minutes!

Comment: Hmm Is there any way to append the results to an existing div (with document.getElementById for example) instead of creating a new one?

Comment: @DanielFelipe then you will be just moving the elements from current position to a new position is that what you need